# How to order tableview data to be displayed in horizontal with no repetition

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx, tableview

I have a tableview where the same data need to be displayed in horizontal way not vertical.
How to order tableview data to be displayed in horizontal way like image below without repeating time.

[Tableview form that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNZDB.png)

code:

```
//list of time from database
time_list.addAll(atjc.findAppointmentTimeEntities());

    tableTime.setItems(time_list);
    tableTime.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col5.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col6.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col7.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col8.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col9.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
    col10.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("time"));
```

EDIT:

I tried with GridPane and adding a ListViews per grid cell. But now i'm only getting a null ListView without items or ListView with only last item.

```
List app_time = atjc.findAppointmentTimeEntities();
    ObservableList app_time2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    int grid_row=0;
    int grid_colum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<app_time.size();i++){
        app_time2.clear();
        app_time2.add(((AppointmentTime)app_time.get(i)).getTime());
        ListView lv =  new ListView();

         appointment_time.add(lv, grid_colum, grid_row);
         grid_colum++;
            if(grid_colum>9){
                grid_row++;
                grid_colum=0;
            }
            lv.setItems(app_time2);


    }
```

[Form i have now with GridPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5osUS.png)

Comment: Are you sure a `TableView` is what you need here? A `GridPane` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @James_D i tried it with grid and labels ( http://imgur.com/a/92sTl ) but i need to get a selected item so it didnt worked for me

Comment: @James_D hi, i tried with `GridPane`  it worked but i'm only getting last item from database or null ListView. Code is above.

Comment: Don't create a new list view on every iteration of the loop

Comment: @James_D ty for your reply, i tried it but its throwing exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT`. I tried to create multiply ListView but again it's getting last item.

Comment: Ok, actually, why are you using `ListView` at all in this version? Why don't you just create and add labels?

Comment: Because i need to select elements on gridpane and to use that data( id of selected time) to make an appointment.

Comment: But using lots of `ListView`s will not help with that, will it?

Comment: I think it will work by initializing `ListVeiw` with `getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()`.

Comment: But each `ListView` will have its own selection model.

Comment: I know it but i thought it will work. I tried it with `Labeles` before making them with `ListView` but i didnt know how to get selected element on `GridPane` and to hover when mouse is on it.